# Caffeine versus Guava cache

Tags: caching, guava, caffeine

According to these [micro benchmarks](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks) it turns out that [Caffeine](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.1.0/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/Caffeine.html) is a way faster than [Guava cache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) in both read and write operations.

What is the secret of Caffeine implementation? How it differs from the Guava Cache?

Am I right that in case of timed expiration Caffeine use a scheduled executor to perform appropriate maintenance operations in background?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The main difference is because Caffeine uses ring buffers to record & replay events, whereas Guava uses `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. The intent was always to migrate Guava over and it made sense to start simpler, but unfortunately there was never interest in accepting those changes. The ring buffer approach avoids allocation, is bounded (lossy), and cheaper to operate against.

The remaining costs are due to a design mismatch. The original author of `MapMaker` was enthusiastic about soft references as the solution to caching problems by deferring it to the GC. Unfortunately while that can seem fast in microbenchmarks, it has horrible performance in practice due to causing stop-the-world GC thrashing. The size-based solution had to be adapted into this work and that is not ideal. Caffeine optimizes for size-based and also gains an improved hash table, whereas Guava handles reference caching more elegantly.

Caffeine doesn't create its own threads for maintenance or expiration. It does defer the cost to the `commonPool`, which slightly improves user-facing latencies but not throughput. A future version might leverage `CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor` to schedule the next expiration event without directly creating threads (for users who have business logic depending on prompt removal notifications).

`ConcurrentLinkedHashMap` and `MapMaker` were written at the same time and CLHM has similar performance to Caffeine. I believe the difference is due to what scenarios the designers favored and optimized for, which impacted how other features would be implemented. There is low hanging fruit to allow Guava to have similar performance profile, but there isn't an internal champion to drive that (and even less so with Caffeine as a favored alternative).